# Can a hole cutter be used with a dremel?

Tags: drill

My dremel has an adjustable speed switch, which makes it a lot easier to control the speed than with a drill. Is there an adapter I can buy so I can attach this [hole cutter](http://www.toolstation.com/shop/Clearance/Power%20Tool%20Accessories/Adjustable%20Hole%20Cutter/d50/sd2675/p47076) (which has a shank that is too big for the dremel), to my dremel?

[image]

On the packaging it says maximum 500RPM.

Comment: What material are you cutting? How thick.  Adjustable dia bits are never as well designed as fixed size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you could find an adapter to connect the bit to a rotary tool, I don't think the rotary tool would hold up to the weight of the bit and the torque it produced.  Rotary tools are **not** designed to handle large amounts of torque.

The weight of a bit like that, and the drag forces it would encounter would likely be too much for the rotary tool to handle.  This would cause the motor of the rotary tool to burn out, simply not spin up to speed, or stop as soon as you started cutting.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not! A Dremel tool would not have the ability to drive this hole cutter, certaqinly once it engaged the surface of what you would be cutting. It would stall the motor and if you persisted, probably kill it by causing it to overheat.

As well, any bearings in the Dremel would be overtaxed by this load, killing them too even if the motor could spin it. The motor will die first though.

You would be far better off simply buying a cheap drill that can handle the load.

Comment: I oviously don't know how to use this thing properly. I have a regular domestic makita drill. It seems to be struggling. I gave it the beans but then the drill spun. It threatened to break my wrist. The shank is hex shaped. All the drill bits my dad uses are round. Do I need a special drill for this bugger?

Comment: @Ageis If the drill feels like it wants to spin instead of the bit, it means either you are forcing the bit (pressing too hard). or the bit has bound up, in which case you should back it up a bit and carefully continue cutting.  If you force the bit, it is very likely the bit will bind and could possibly hurt you.  When working with hole saws, it's always slow and steady.  You want to make sure you stay straight, and let the bit do the work.

Comment: Feed the bit SLOWLY. If you try to jam the point into the wood, all it will do is jam up, and then as you say, try to break your wrist. You want to peel off a shaving with the cutter, not massive chunks of wood. So back off on how hard you push. There is a balance between cutting fast and jamming it up. You need to find that line.

Comment: Note: the hex shank is irrelevant. All that does is prevent the bit from spinning in the chuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you could get the bit to fit into the dremel somehow then you could probably cut holes in extremely light material, like balsa wood or soft plastic (if you push really, really slowly). However, dremel tools are made for high speed and not torque and normal use with a bit like that would definitely burn it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you overspeed this little device, it will come apart and put holes in you, possibly even killing you in the process.

The Dremel tool does not have enough torque at 500RPM to properly use a fly-cutter like this and if you accidentally run it up to 5,000 rpm, the fly-cutter will not be balanced for such speed, will probably give a good wobble, bend the chuck and depart the Dremel tool.

Drill motors are made to have the low speed and high torque needed to use such devices.

Answer (score 0):

Most Dremel-style rotary tools spin at high speeds; around 25,000-45,000 rpm. I'm sure you could find a large enough chuck or suitable adapter though. Or maybe you could modify the shaft/shank of the bit. All in all, it's probably not a great idea. something is bound to break; the electric motor, the cutting bit, or the material you're wanting to cut.